# Hide attributes from product sort by list in Magento

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way to only show attributes in the Sort By list if there are products with that attribute on the page? My catalog has many different attributes but only one or two may apply to each product.

ie if I have attributes height, weight, color and I am looking at a page of t-shirts, I want to not sort by height or weight as these are irrelevent. On another page I might be listing boxes, so height and weight then do become relevent and should be added to the sort by list.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood. I have deleted my answer

Comment: DRAJI you were correct to some extend. you need to get filterable attributes after performing your solution. e.g. $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes(); and then you can filter the "Sort By" attributes based on this $attributes.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi okay. Please post it as answer, It would be helpful to someone who need result like this concept

Comment: @DushyantJoshi okay. I have reposted my answer

Comment: @DushyantJoshi $attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes(); is it enough or else? or please post as a new answer. I'm not clear with this point

Comment: @DRAJI it should work

Comment: @matt,  please accept the answer if it worked, else other people wont be able to know.

Answer (score 1):

In Manage attributes, set "**Use In Layered Navigation**" as **Filterable(with results)** instead of **Filterable(no results)** to those attributes which you don't want to show when that attribute value doesn't exist on products

[image]

After performing the above solution. **in Toolbar.phtml** (or whereever if your extending),do the following,

```
 <?php
$orders=$this->getAvailableOrders();
$new_orders[]=array();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($orders);

$layer = Mage::getModel("catalog/layer");
$category=Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$category = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId());
$layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
$attributes = $layer->getFilterableAttributes();


$attributesCodes[]=array();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
{

    $filterBlockName = 'catalog/layer_filter_attribute';
    $attributesCodes[]=$attribute->getAttributeCode();

    $result = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock($filterBlockName)->setLayer($layer)->setAttributeModel($attribute)->init();

}
print_r($attributesCodes);

foreach($orders as $key_order=>$lbl_order){
    if(!in_array($key_order,$attributesCodes)) continue;
    $new_orders[]=$key_order;
}
print_r($new_orders);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure this will remove from "Sort By" Drop Down? I do not think so

Comment: Yeah that didn't work for the "sort by" drop-down, only for the sidebar layered nav.

Comment: uff sorry. I will delete my answer

Comment: Your edit post was rejected by moderator, i think. Please check whether edit content or right or wrong? @DushyantJoshi

Comment: All credits of this answer are only for you @DushyantJoshi Thank you